# IOS Push Notification while device OFF or out of network

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am developing an IOS app and I noticed that the notification arrives only when the device is ON and has internet access but if the device is OFF or out of network then **NO** notifications will be received.

Comment: So .... is there a question here?

Comment: And you're surprised by this?  If it;s off or out of network there;s no way for it to be delivered - would you expect a call to complete if the phone was off or out of network?

Comment: remote push notification solved my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple's Quality of Service https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html

> It retains only one notification per application on a device:
>
> Apple Push Notification Service includes a default Quality of Service
>   (QoS) component that performs a store-and-forward function. If APNs
>   attempts to deliver a notification but the device is offline, the QoS
>   stores the notification. It retains only one notification per
>   application on a device: the last notification received from a
>   provider for that application. When the offline device later
>   reconnects, the QoS forwards the stored notification to the device.
>   The QoS retains a notification for a limited period before deleting
>   it.